# Spring Cloud Contract provider return same as request

Tags: spring-cloud, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I'm working with two microservices using [Spring Cloud Contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/). One providing its contract, and the other one consuming it. In one scenario the provider response is the same that the request.

So the provider contract is like this:

```
  Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/provider/foo'
    body(
        "foo": $(regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}"))          
    )
  }
  response {
    status 200
    body(
        "fooResponse": fromRequest().body("\$.foo")
    )
 }
```

And the generated wiremock mapping:

```
{
  "id" : "a80c0871-f4c0-49e3-8cc1-94de39899669",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/provider/foo",
    "method" : "POST",
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.['foo'] =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}/)]"
    } ]
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{\"fooResponse\":\"{{{jsonpath this '$.foo'}}}\"}",
    "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
  },
  "uuid" : "a80c0871-f4c0-49e3-8cc1-94de39899669",
  "scenarioName" : "scenarioReturnSameAsRequest",
  "requiredScenarioState" : "Started"
}
```

But when my code calls to the provider, with foo as any text, the wiremock returns:

```
{
    "fooResponse" : "{{{jsonpath this '$.foo'}}}"
}
```

How can I build a contract that responses the same parameters as the request body?

---

**Edit**

I tried with a fixed value on the response and works fine:

```
  Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/provider/foo'
    body(
        "foo": $(regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}"))          
    )
  }
  response {
    status 200
    body(
        "fooResponse": "fooValue"
    )
 }
```

Now wiremock return:

```
{
    "fooResponse" : "fooValue"
}
```

Maybe is not supported getting from request a regex value?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mapping should contain `request.body` instead of `this`. Also I wonder if you need to use 3 times a `{` or just 2 times. Or do you need to escape these?

Possible mapping:

```
"response" : {
  "status" : 200,
  "body" : "{\"fooResponse\":\"{{jsonpath request.body '$.foo'}}\"}",
  "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
},
```

See also the chapter `JSONPath helper` on http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating

Comment: The mappings are automatically generated from the contracts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. You can try to use `value()` like this:

```
"fooResponse": value(fromRequest().body('$.foo'))
```